# Why would feval return NaN in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting, spline

I have a bunch of points in 2D for which I know the value, and I'd like to fit a cubic spline through them to interpolate some other data around using MATLAB.

My code looks like:

```
fitobject = fit(x,y,'cubicinterp');
yy=feval(fitobject,xx)
```

with the following inputs:

Coordinates

```
x = [...
   313     3;
   313     5;
   313     7;
   315     3;
   315     5;
   317     3;
   319     5];
```

Values

```
y = [...
   28.0779;
   28.0186;
   11.6220;
   16.7640;
   23.7139;
  -14.7882;
  -20.4626];
```

Interpolation points

```
xx = [...
   313     3;
   313     4;
   313     5;
   313     6;
   313     7;
   313     8;
   313     9;
   314     3;
   314     5;
   314     7;
   315     3;
   315     4;
   315     5;
   315     6;
   315     7;
   316     3;
   316     5;
   317     3;
   317     4;
   317     5;
   318     3;
   319     5;
   319     6;
   319     7;
   320     5];
```

In my output vector `yy`, I get several `NaN` values. To me, the input data look clean (they are all finite values and there's no `NaN`). I don't get what would cause `feval` to return `NaN` when fitting data. Why couldn't it give the best possible fit, even if it is bad? Is there an error in my approach?

I browsed a bit and it seems that the same question had been asked a bunch of times on mathworks forums, but no one gave a clear answer.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't have the curve-fitting toolbox. Do you have a way to examine the fitted function? Maybe some of the data-points you use to evaluate the fitted function are such that they cause [`NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html)

Comment: You can use `yy=fitobject(xx)` syntax too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because an *interpolation* cannot be used as an *extrapolation*:

```
  %xx(:,1)    xx(:,2)  yy

  313.0000    3.0000   28.0779
  313.0000    4.0000   29.5074
  313.0000    5.0000   28.0186
  313.0000    6.0000   22.3233
  313.0000    7.0000   11.6220
  313.0000    8.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  313.0000    9.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  314.0000    3.0000   24.1239
  314.0000    5.0000   27.5130
  314.0000    7.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  315.0000    3.0000   16.7640
  315.0000    4.0000   21.7028
  315.0000    5.0000   23.7139
  315.0000    6.0000   11.2710
  315.0000    7.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  316.0000    3.0000    1.4641   
  316.0000    5.0000   13.9662
  317.0000    3.0000  -14.7882
  317.0000    4.0000   -5.4876
  317.0000    5.0000    2.7781
  318.0000    3.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  319.0000    5.0000  -20.4626
  319.0000    6.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  319.0000    7.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
  320.0000    5.0000       NaN   % xx exceeds bounds of original x interval
```

In other words, you're trying to get data beyond the boundaries of your original surface data (extrapolation), which is usually already quite dangerous, and `fit` does not even allow you to do it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I thought "fit" was using the bunch of points I gave as input to return a function defined everywhere.

Comment: @Virginie: if you want , you can change to `nearestinterp` to copy the  values *on* the border, or `biharmonicinterp` to continue outside the boundary. Note that your values will completely explode in that case; a basic side effect of using an accurate *interpolation* for *extrapolation* :)

Comment: Now that I understand what's going on I think it makes more sense to care only for values inside the interpolation interval. Thanks for the trick anyway!

Comment: @Virginie : I agree with your first comment, I would have thought that a function is being returned which could be evaluated outside the initial range of data (with all the separate issues that might arise from an extrapolation as Rody Oldenhuis mentioned)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the points which come up as NaN lie outside of the interpolation.  You can plot it to take a look.

[image: cubic interpolation]

The code I used to play with this is as follows: (Note that I set the NaNs to -25 just so that they could be plotted)

```
x = [313     3;
    313     5;
    313     7;
    315     3;
    315     5;
    317     3;
    319     5];
y = [
    28.0779
    28.0186
    11.6220
    16.7640
    23.7139
    -14.7882
    -20.4626];

fitobject = fit(x,y,'cubicinterp');

xx = [
    313     3
    313     4
    313     5
    313     6
    313     7
    313     8
    313     9
    314     3
    314     5
    314     7
    315     3
    315     4
    315     5
    315     6
    315     7
    316     3
    316     5
    317     3
    317     4
    317     5
    318     3
    319     5
    319     6
    319     7
    320     5];


yy = fitobject(xx);
badindices = isnan(yy);
yy(badindices) = -25;

plot(fitobject, xx, yy, 'Exclude', badindices)
```

By the way, notice that I'm not using feval, but a direct call to `fitobject`

Comment: The plot is exactly what I wanted to see. I didn't know I could call fitobject directly either. Very helpful answer, thanks!